# why using LIKE with TIMESTAMPS do not work in DB2

Tags: sql, database, select, db2

i have problem using `LIKE` structure in `DB2`:
for example:

```
select * from TEST where TIME LIKE '2012-03-04-%'
```

FYI. - `TIME` is `TIMESTAMP` data type.

why using `LIKE` with `TIMESTAMPS` do not work?

Additional info: i want to extract data from one single day provided by user in select statement.

Comment: Because timestamps aren't strings? If you really want to treat them like string, cast them to strings and specifiy the format you want. But for this type of query, don't cast the timestamp to something else, use it natively - there are a plethora of functions and constructs for dealing with this datatype natively. Stop treating them like strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just expanding on @mortb's answer, I'd either use `BETWEEN` or

```
WHERE time >= '2012-03-04' AND time < '2012-03-05'
```

The advantage of using `BETWEEN` or a comparison that using `casts` and `LIKE` will mean that if there is an index on `time` it wouldn't be able to be used due to the casting.

Comment: +1 : For not using `BETWEEN` with continuous values. For not hiding the search field in a function. And for not using string manipulation to deal with `TIMESTAMP`. Why do people think everything is a string!?

Comment: I guess the confusion started when they added '' (quotation marks) around the dates in the first place. When writing SQL for an access database you can surround dates with # (#2012-04-04#) instead of as regular string literals. That seems more unambiguous.

Comment: @mortb - Dates don't have quotes around them.  In your query you have two string constants.  As `TIMESTAMP >= STRING` isn't possible, one or other data-type needs to be *implicitly* cast to the other.  Based on the order of precidence of data-types, the strings get implicitly cast to TIMESTAMPs.  Just as if you used a CAST() function yourself.

Answer (score 5):

LIKE is for string (char, varchar) datatypes. Use `WHERE time BETWEEN '2012-03-04' AND '2012-03-04 23:59:59.998'`

Comment: Your proposal includes one second from `2012-03-05`, which is not expected

Comment: Maybe WHERE time BETWEEN '2012-03-04' AND '2012-04-04 23:59:59.998' would be better then?

Comment: @mortb: No, the correct-to-detail answer is the one provided by beny23.

Comment: For *discrete* values, `BETWEEN` can be fine. For ***continuous*** values, however, use `>= AND <`. It's not SQL, it's understanding data-types and their behaviours.

Comment: Yeah, >= AND < seems more elegant

Comment: @mortb - It's no so much elegance, but precision.  `BETWEEN` will have a boundry condition error because it includes a single point of the subsequent range.  Even if you use `BETWEEN ValueA AND ValueB-aTinyBit`, you still need to make sure the `TinyBit` that you subtract really is the smallest possible amount.  With FLOATs that's impossible, different date/time data-types have varying degrees of precision, it's all a recipe for hidden margins of error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
where time between
    to_date('2016-06-17 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') and
    to_date('2016-06-18 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'
```