# Searching Gridview by Date, but the Calendar control picker (that is DateTime) includes the date and also the time, example: 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, datetime

I have a GridView that should be populated according to a selected date, so I made the use of the **`Calendar control`**.

**The problem**

- **Since the Calendar control's selected date is DateTime, unfortunately the selected date in the `Calendar` seems to be is in the format**: `dd-MM-yyy` 
  *example* 2013-02-15
- **while the `date field` in the Database is of type `datetime` meaning**: `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS.ms` 
   *example* 2013-02-15 09:02:03.253

So there will be no result since the Calendar control and the Database field are of different types.

**What i tried**

```asp
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from table1 where start_date Like '% " & calendar1.SelectedDate.Date & " %' "
```

As you can see i worked the sqldatasource in code behind and i made the use of `Like` But even with the use of `Like` no results show **due to Database having not only date but time too**.

I was also thinking to change the sql query itself, and precisely the field `start_date`, to omit the time (HH:mm:SS.ms) but is it possible to do so?

### Edit:

Even if the Calendar Control's selected date and the field in the database are both DateTime, the search won't work because when searching with the Calendar Control its query will be Date and Time example `2013-01-01 00:00:00.000` while in the DB the time is not always 00:00:00 thus the need of Between as the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Date to extract records from a database using a DateTime field. I dont think using LIKE on dates is a good idea. Specify From and To date ranges to get one day worth of data:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from table1 where start_date >" & calendar1.SelectedDate.Date & " AND start_date < " & calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(1)
```

Or using the BETWEEN operator:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from table1 where start_date between " & calendar1.SelectedDate.Date & " AND " & calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(1)
```

Comment: Using between is a bad idea.  Your first answer is ok, but you didn't mentioning using query parameters.

Comment: Why is Between a bad idea? I agree with query parameters but to answer the question and it get it working for OP in the simplest form I didn't bother with SQL Injection, besides how can you put SQL injection in a Date?

Comment: Using between is a bad idea because it includes the start of the following day.

Comment: @Dan Thank you but I am afraid that I do not understand why use the query parameters? what for?

Comment: @Jeremy the gt and the lt didn't work for some reason that i don't know it, while between worked for me and i notice something new, between is also useful if i also have two calendars, so thank you.

Comment: @Jeremy I found out why Like didn't work, `LIKE is for string (char, varchar) datatypes. Use WHERE time BETWEEN` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009553/why-using-like-with-timestamps-do-not-work-in-db2

Comment: @Jeremey and if you don't mind i added the single quotes to your answer for it to work, if you can accept the edit please. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.SelectedDate` is `DateTime`. So just change `calendar1.SelectedDate.Date` to `calendar1.SelectedDate`.

Proof: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate.aspx

Comment: thank you for correcting that, but unfortunately that alone didn't work, still no result.

Comment: converting your selected date to varchar and the compare it to the date picker date.
where convert(varchar, your_date_value) like date_picker

Comment: @compliance what do you have there? MySQL? MSSQL?

Comment: it is microsoft sql server, and i think that it does not work though both the Calendar and the field in the DB are DateTime, because when using the calendar it has the date, example: dd-MM-yyyy + it adds hours by default, example if i choose 2013-02-19 it will actually be: 2013-02-19 00:00:00.000 thus it never worked, I may be wrong but I think that is the reason why it didn't work. Nevertheless I don't know why Like was of no help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting only matters when you are displaying data.  Basically, dates are integers and datetimes are floats.

Create a .net DateTime object from whatever is selected in your datepicker.  Then convert it to a query parameter which you use in your query.

Comment: Thank you but I am afraid that I did not understand that as I am only learning so a beginner.